# Chicago Style - see note x instead of short version

Tags: biblatex, endnotes, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

For a certain journal, I have to use Chicago Style with endnotes. I may use "Ibid." if the reference already appeared in the previous endnote.

If the reference did not appear in the previous endnote, but some endnotes before, I have to write "Author (see note x above)".

Currently I use the biblatex-chicago Package

```
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

but the output here is only the shortened version of the reference for subsequent references.

How can I change to a style, replacing shortened forms with a reference to the first mentioned reference?

Comment: Even though your question is reasonably clear without a code example you can make our lives easier by providing a small [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that can get us started. That way we all start from the same assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` does not really lend itself to modifications. If you use the code below, you will probably not be fully CMS compatible any more, so proceed at your own risk.

The basic infrastructure is stolen from `verbose-inote` which already implements such a style.

Since some of `biblatex-chicago`'s macros have to be quite intricate to get things right, the number of lines of code needed is a bit higher than it could be with other styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber,singletitle]{biblatex-chicago}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{above}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{above = {above}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}\frenchspacing}%
      {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \csxdef{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
  \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}

\newtoggle{cbx:pageref}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{%
       togl {cms@allshort}%
       or
       test {\ifbibliography}%
     }%
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}
      \addspace
      \bibstring{above}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite{worman} dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite{worman} dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem\autocite{knuth:ct:a} ipsum\autocite{knuth:ct:b} dolor\autocite{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes of the first page]

Comment: Almost perfect. How can I include the "above" into "(see note 1)" so that I get "(see note 1 above)"? And is there a way to include the "title", if there are multiple references of one author in a note I am referring to?

Comment: @feder80 I have updated the answer to include the 'above'. We could include the title if there are several titles by the same author, it would be more complicated to do that conditional on that being in a particular note. Can you clarify what exactly you want. (Keeping in mind that it would be quite a bit more complicated to check if the author is unique per footnote as compared to the entire document.)

Comment: It should look as follows: Note 1: Author X, "Title 1", Journal etc.; Author X, "Title 2" Journal etc.; Author Y, "Title 3" Journal etc.
Note 2: Author Y (see note 1 above).
Note 3: Author X, "Title 2" (see note 1 above).

Comment: @feder80 I can do that easily. But  Note 1: Author X, Title 1, Author X, Title 2. Note 2: Author Y, Title 3. Note 3: Author Y, Title 4. Note 4: Author Y (see note 2). I can't do, I could do 'Note 4: Author Y, Title 3 (see note 2)'

Comment: ok, that would also be fine. I really wonder, why a Journal chooses such a horrible citation style!

Comment: @feder80 Have a look at the edit. The image has not been updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you. Just two last questions: 1) how can I add a period at the end of a note? 2) How can I tell LaTeX to use the short title (if available) in the subsequent references?

Comment: @feder80 In my examples there always is a full stop at the end of each note. The notes already use the short title (they use `labeltitle`, but that means they prefer `shorttitle` to `title`) as you can see in fn. 9 of the example. It reads 'Knuth, TeXbook (see note 7 above)'. Here 'TeXbook' is the `shorttitle`, the (long)`title` is `The TeX book`.

Comment: you are right, sorry!

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate that!